# UI to allow both and-ing / or-ing on a facet menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I have the following menu in my application:

[image]

As it currently is, a user can select one or more items and the filter is OR-ed. However, I also want the user to be able to AND items, if they so choose. Have any of you ever come across an example where a filter can be and-ed or or-ed based on the user's preference? If so, how would this be displayed?

Comment: you can use `input type="radio"` for OR-ed and `input type="checkbox"` for AND-ed selections and switch the type based on user preference

Comment: @maioman not necessarily -- It would be a checkbox-like input for each. For example, what if I want 5 items all ORed together? Tarzan OR Robin Hood OR Les Miserables? How could I use a radio button (which only allows one item to be selected) to do this?

Comment: if you choose more than one  it can't be a radio type, it needs to be checkbox...  maybe I misunderstood the or-ed | and-ed distinction

Comment: May be that would be a question for user experience ?